# Collecting telemetry data from AppSheet

Tags: google-sheets, telemetry, google-appsheet

I'm looking to build a new app for in-house users (employees) and want to try out AppSheet. However, I really want to collect telemetry (usage) data so I know who is using what, when, etc.

I don't see any information about this, even after searching here and the wider web.

Is it possible to collect usage data from users using AppSheet?

Comment: In order to better understand your post, can you please specify where this telemetry data is hosted and how you can retrieve that data (API, gRPC ,etc)?

Comment: By telemetry data I mean when the app is opened, what is clicked, etc. Tracking this in a code-based app is easy enough, but I am unsure how to track this in a no-code solution.

Comment: Start by reading [Monitor: The Essentials](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10104996?hl=en)